# Check number one

Tags: word-choice

I'd like someone to clear it up for me the meaning of this sentence from Priory School by Conan Doyle.

*“Check number one,” said Holmes, looking gloomily over the rolling expanse of the moor.*

This is uttered by Holmes when he found a highly-expected segment of his survey almost fruitless. 
Is this "check number one" a set phrase, idiom or something. (I couldn't find it up in dictionaries though). 
Or he just said it and meant somewhere like..
Tick this part on this first part (they stared the survey with this part of the moor,hence the word Number one?) as finished, we have other parts of the moor to look into. 
Am I right?  Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure _check_ is used in the sense of a setback in the progress of the investigation - the first one they had encountered. It does not mean _tick off_ in British English.

Comment: Without more text for context, it would be hard to determine the meaning. *"Check number one"* could be *"Examine item one for information/anomalies"*

Comment: The full text is online. I had a look for interest's sake and agree with Kate Bunting. It's the same sense of *check* as in *check your progress* or *checks and balances*.